# Primary key in an association table

Tags: database, associations, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Let' s say there is a small database with tables `Person(ID, Name)` and `Product(ID, Name, Color)`. ID column is obviously the Primary key of each table. I want as usual to add an association Many-to-Many table `Order(PersonID, ProductID, Date)`. I have had the impression that the Primary Key of table Order is the combination `(PersonID, ProductID)`. However in some aproaches the combination `(PersonID, ProductID, Date)` is recommended as the Primary Key. What is the diference? I think that even if `(PersonID, ProductID)` is the Primary Key, to each combination `(PersonID, ProductID)` corresponds only one Date. If the later is true when should one include the Date to the Primary Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there can only be one date associated with a Person/Product combination, then the PK should be `(PersonID, ProductId)`. You should only include the `Date` in the PK if there can be multiple associations like this, and the date is what distinguishes them. If you include the Date in the PK when you don't need it, the database won't report an error if you try to create duplicate rows with the same Person/Product but a different date.

UPDATE:

Your comment about adding an ID column led me to realize that this isn't quite right. You just need to declare `(PersonID, ProductID)` as a Unique Key, it doesn't have to be the primary key. You could then have an ID field as the primary key; the unique key will prevent duplicates. The same thing could be done if you added the `Date` to the PK.

However, in a properly normalized database, the Primary Key should be the only Unique Key in a table. A relation is a mapping of Key->Data, and the PK should reflect this mapping.

Comment: OK, I have been deliberating since I wrote the question and I reached to the same conclusion as described in the answer. However, it strikes me that adding the Date to the PK is the same as adding an ID to the association table, which is inappropriate. Is there a common and acceptable approach to get over this?